# Putting redux state into local state with useEffect() doesn't change the local state completeley

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, use-effect

I know that setState is asynchronous, but I have a weird problem with it.

My shortened code:

```js
// My imports including my own component for an input switch (Switchbox)

function EditDoc(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [privateDoc, setPrivateDoc] = useState(true);

  const {
    editDoc,
    createDoc,
    data: { docs },
  } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    let id = props.match.params.docId;

    if (id in docs) {
      setPrivateDoc(docs[id].privateDoc);
      setName(docs[id].name);
    }
  }, []);

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    if (id in docs) {
      editDoc(name, privateDoc);
    } else {
      createDoc(name, privateDoc);
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          autoFocus="autoFocus"
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Switchbox
          title="Public document"
          checked={!privateDoc}
          function={() => setPrivateDoc(!privateDoc)}
        />
        <button
           type="reset"
           onClick={props.history.goBack}
        />
        <button
           type="submit"
        />
        </div>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

CreateLearningUnit.propTypes = {
  editDoc: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  createDoc: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.data,
});

const mapActionsToProps = {
  editDoc,
  createDoc,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(EditDoc);
```

The Switchbox is always showing true after the first rendering, which is set in `const [private, setPrivate] = useState(true);`. My Switchbox element is not the problem, it works fine in other cases, and in this case it also works fine after toggling the switch once, but it seems like useState() is overwriting the things set in useEffect().

Now the weird thing: With name for example, everything works great, name gets set and shows up as the value in the input. SetPrivate() in useEffect is doing something too, but private is only displayed correctly after changing it one time. And yes, I know, that I use the negative of private, it shows `true` in both cases: docs[id].private true and false.

Could you please help me with this problem?

I already tried using local variables and using `useRef()` with a constant but that doesn't work either.

**Edit: I changed private to privateDoc, in my original code it is a longer name**

Comment: Since you're not passing any dependencies to `useEffect` this means it's only to render once on mount. And since you're using props to set the initial values on private/name, why not use the callback in `useState` to set the initial props instead of using `useEffect`>

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I need to do it in useEffect, because I check if the doc is in docs first. If it is not in docs the user can create a new doc. I will edit the code so it is better understandable.

Comment: Can you make sure that docs[id].private comes as a bool value

Comment: Also, `private` is a reserved keyword in JS. I'd suggesting altering to `isPrivate`

Comment: In my original code it has a longer name. But that could have been a problem, yes 

Comment: What do you mean by "comes as a bool value"?

Comment: Taking a string for example, would cause that behavior: !'false'

Comment: Oh, right, I'll check that.

Comment: No, it is always a boolean. If I build a new useEffect() function like that:
`useEffect(() => { console.log(privateDoc); }, [privateDoc]);` it always shows true after reloading the page, even if `docs[id].privateDoc` is false.
After the first switch it shows false, which is the right behavior for the switchbox-function.